# Zend .htaccess configuration not working in Ubuntu

Tags: zend-framework, apache2, ubuntu-10.04

Hi I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - the Lucid Lynx
i create a project by

zf create project test

this command automatically generates a .htaccess file which didn't work
I configured my webserver (Apache2) by editing
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default file 
setting

```
<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

and i am getting the following error

```
Internal Server Error
/**************************************************************************************/
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
/****************************************************************************************/
```

please help me

Comment: Please, tail your /var/log/apache2/error.log so we can see the cause.

Comment: hi my /var/log/apache2/error.log is as follows

Comment: [Tue Oct 19 18:24:57 2010] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /var/www/testing/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You haven't loaded mod_rewrite, so Apache doesn't know what the RewriteEngine line means.

On ubuntu you can probably do (as a super user):

```
a2enmod rewrite
apache2ctl restart
```

Otherwise you'll have to edit the apache config and add a line like this to load the module

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

The path on your system may be different.